# Copy materialized view to a new table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

I have a materialized view with which I have to create a new table in cassandra.

I tried this but it isn't working.
`CREATE TABLE accounts_bk WHERE SELECT * FROM accounts_Mview`

Also Will COPY command work to copy from materialized view to new table?

Answer (score 2):

"create table as select" is not supported by Cassandra right now.

COPY could work, but it does involve pulling the entire table to the server running cqlsh, then loading it back up.

Spark is often recommended for these types of transformations.
https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-spark-and-cassandra

Comment: for reference, "create table as select" is in Cassandra's JIRA here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8234

Comment: I've tried COPY command on materialized view and its not working, I got error message "Column family '$name_of_view' not found" :-(

Comment: Where is that string in the error message coming from? Are you just revising the table name, or is that literally what it says?
What is the output of `DESC` on your keyspace? Is there a chance your table name has mixed case?

Comment: I just wrote it as a placeholder for my table name, the error message says: "Column family 'event' not found" . Where `event` is the name of the materialized view.

Comment: @TomasBartalos seems like the COPY command is not applicable for materialized views. did you manage to find another way to do it?